# How to POST two variable using ajax for save the data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I want to POST two variables. One is a JSON string and another one is a textbox value I am using C# for SQL server connection. Can anyone please check what is wrong in my code.

```
var myjsonstring = JSON.stringify(myjson);
var filename = $("#fname").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/name/Service/SaveData",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        jsonobject: myjsonstring,filename
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
}
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `jsonobject: myjsonstring,filename` is invalid. Send the values as two separate properties of an object

Comment: See eisbehr's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an normal `object` to `data` of `$.ajax`:

```
data: {
    myjsonstring: myjsonstring,
    filename: filename
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use json stringify method for post data, you need to pass json object for passing multiple variables as mentioned below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/Exebenus/Service/SaveData",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        myjson: myjson,
        filename:filename
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
}
});
```